# How to get text from edittext in other layout

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two layouts (name is regis and log)

I can't get Text from EditText in regis.xml to log.xml when I use code

> setContentView(R.layout.log);
>
> ...
>
> final EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
>
> String usr = user.getText().toString();

Because 'edt1' is element other layout (edt1 is id EditText regis.xml)

How to get edt1 into log.xml ?
Example please

thanks you very much

Comment: what do you want to do?? Get the text from one activity in another activity??

Comment: you want to pass the data from one screen to another?

Comment: using static variable you can access text in android activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the LayoutInflater class.  Create a LayoutInflater, and then inflate the layout file containing the view you would like to access (in this case the EditText).

```
    LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    View regisText = factory.inflate(R.layout.regis, null);
    EditText user = (EditText) regisText.findViewById(R.id.edt1); 
    String usr = user.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Hi, does this create a new instance of your EditText? What about if you wanted to use the same instance from the EditText, and simply change its value (user makes changes, repeatedly if needed). Do you know how to get the same instance from another layout?

Answer (score -1):

make your

```
String usr as public static String usr
```

and access it in another activity